# Not getting the dropdown list using typeahead

Tags: jquery, typeahead.js

I have problem with impelemting typeahead script. The problem is i dont get dropdown list of suggestion for some reason. It's basic script that retrieve info from a local array.
[Take a look at the code][1]

[1]:     https://jsfiddle.net/d1ycqemc/#`enter code here`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d1ycqemc/#

Comment: [Just in case you were still stuck](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/d1ycqemc/20/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I would recommend looking through the jsFiddle documentation.](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/tutorial.html)

The jsfiddle was not setup correctly.  You need to add an external resource (on the left side of the page) pointing to the typeahead library.

In the javascript panel, you needed to click on the gear/cog icon and point it to using jQuery - which typeahead requires.

The revised html for use in a fiddle:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="the-basics">
    <input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="States of USA" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The revised javascript for use in a fiddle:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
];

$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
}, {
  name: 'states',
  source: substringMatcher(states)
});
```

[Here is your fiddle corrected with those changes, and the script tags removed.](https://jsfiddle.net/whipdancer/d1ycqemc/7/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing jQuery and typeahead libraries. Use Chrome developer, press F12 and you will see the missing dependencies. In jsfiddle, include the libraries in the 'external resources' on the left instead of putting them in the javascript block

`<!-- This is JQuery Script ---->
enter code here<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- This is typeahead Script ---->
<script src="jquery.typeahead.min.js"></script>`

https://jsfiddle.net/05z5ddv0/

Good luck!